# 'root' does not name a type error

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors

While compiling the following C++ code,

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
    TreeNode* construct(vector<int> nums,int start, int end)
    {
        if(start>end)
            return NULL;

        int i,index,v = INT_MIN;
        for(i=start;i<=end;i++)

            if(nums[i]>v)
            {
                v = nums[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(v);
        root->left = construct(nums,start,index-1);
        root->right = construct(nums,index+1,end);
        return root;
    }
public:
    TreeNode* constructMaximumBinaryTree(vector<int>& nums) {
        return construct(nums,0,nums.size()-1);
    }
};
```

I got the following error :

```
Line 27: 'root' does not name a type
```

I got many articles on this error, but none of them seem to solve the problem. 
Using **malloc()** also does not work here.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is TreeNode struct commented out in your code ? If so how do you expect it to find it?

Comment: Are you sure it's your only error reported?

Comment: which line is `Line 27` and do you include the declaration of `TreeNode` ? You better provide a [mcve]

Comment: or was TreeNode forward declared and now its missing the header?

Comment: Is this code written in the header file ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `root` variable is not known by the compiler as its definition is commented out.
You also have a brace problem as the `for` loop needs one probably since you have a closing one after the `if`.

Something, as follows, should do.

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
   };

class Solution {
    TreeNode* construct(vector<int> nums,int start, int end)
    {
        if(start>end)
            return NULL;

        int i,index,v = INT_MIN;
        for(i=start;i<=end;i++){ //here a missing brace

            if(nums[i]>v)
            {
                v = nums[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
        TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(v);
        root->left = construct(nums,start,index-1);
        root->right = construct(nums,index+1,end);
        return root;
    }
public:
    TreeNode* constructMaximumBinaryTree(vector<int>& nums) {
        return construct(nums,0,nums.size()-1);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the example provided is quite unclear, but this is how the code should be formatted.

Note: I don't have access to a compiler at the moment to test this.

> In the header file
>
> Solution.h

```
// Definition for a binary tree node.
struct TreeNode 
{
    int val;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
    TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};

class Solution 
{
public:

   Solution();
   ~Solution();

   TreeNode* construct(vector<int> nums,int start, int end);
   TreeNode* constructMaximumBinaryTree(vector<int>& nums);
};
```

> In the CPP file
>
> Solution.cpp

```
Solution::Solution()
{
    // Init any members
}

Solution::~Solution()
{
    // Delete any members
}

TreeNode* Solution::construct(vector<int> nums,int start, int end)
{
    if(start>end)
        return NULL;

    int i,index,v = INT_MIN;
    for(i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {

        if(nums[i]>v)
        {
            v = nums[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    TreeNode* root = new TreeNode(v);
    root->left = construct(nums,start,index-1);
    root->right = construct(nums,index+1,end);
    return root;
}

TreeNode* Solution::constructMaximumBinaryTree(vector<int>& nums) 
{
    return construct(nums,0,nums.size()-1);
}
```